# PHP: Pull all images from a specified directory using relative image path

Tags: php, path, directory, gallery, root

I am trying to create a gallery where images are automatically pulled from a images directory.

When I `foreach()` each image it returns however it pulls the entire root path as the image src

`/home/dev/public_html/assets/images/`

this causes the images not to show and shows dead linked images on screen. I need the relative path like this:

`/assets/images/imagename.jpg`

How would I set a base path/URL?

```
$dirname = "/home/dev/public_html/assets/images/";                              

$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

I tried setting `$dirname` to this

```
$dirname = "/assets/images/";
```

But I get no result and nothing pulls through at all.

The file i am creating this in, is located outside the `public_html` folder, i believe this could be casing the issue but the file cannot be relocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would edit the loop in order to remove unnecessary string from path:

```
foreach($images as $image) {
    $src = str_replace('/home/dev/public_html' ,'', $image) ;   
    echo '<img src="'.$src.'" /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could may make use of `scandir()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Somethink like:

Edit: Changed the code a bit, so scandir only take files, otherwise the first two placed in the array are folders for the parent folders.

```
$dir = "assets/images/";
$images = scandir($dir);

foreach($images as $image) {
     if($image != '.' && $image != '..') {
          echo ' <img src="assets/images/'.$image.'"><br>';
     }
}
```

Hope this helped. If not, let me know, so I can change my answer. But I think it should be fine, as far as I understood what you're trying.

Comment: I added your suggested code, however I got the following error with no returned results:  

Warning: scandir(/assets/images/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/dev/target-pages/themes/gallery.php on line 27

Comment: Okay stop. I don't get it what you're doing. Can you please show us your file structure? Btw. I just tested the code on my live server with some random images, it works perfectly. So your only problem is that you haven't placed the script at the right place / I haven't put in the right path - what I can't, since I don't know your file structure. Simply give me one full path to the image folder, and the full path to the script. So I can adapt my code.